# use Switch statement to add multiple colors in flutter listview

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use **switch statement or if else** statement to add multiple colors to listview

I want to use switch statement in below code for 10 different colors. if you know this answer then please help

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      color: (index % 10 == 0) ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      child: ListTile(
        title: ...
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

**If you need more code then please comment on question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    Color color;
    switch (index % 10) {
      case 0: 
        color = Colors.red;
        break;
      case 1: 
        color = Colors.blue;
        break;
      ... // and so on, up to 9
      default: 
        color = Colors.black;
    }

    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: ListTile(
        title: ...
      ),
    );
  },
```

Comment: Thank you very much..what if I want to add multiple gradient colors instead of simple colors

Comment: @ramanraman I'm not sure about what you're asking. You can extract this switch to a function, and then call it multiple times with different indices (like i from grandient start and i+1 for gradient end).

Comment: If you're looking for gradient fills, you'll have to create a `decoration:` on Container, but that's off topic. A simple search will find resources on how to create gradients. After that, this approach will still be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I call random color:

```
Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt() << 0)
              .withOpacity(1.0);
```

In your case:

```
Color(index << 0).withOpacity(1.0);
```

Comment: It was helpful...Thank you

Comment: You can simplify the random color to: `Color(math.Random().nextInt(0xFFFFFF)).withOpacity(1.0);` and you can remove the `<< 0` in the second line which simplifies it to: `Color(index).withOpacity(1.0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: index % 4 == 0
               ? Colors.green
               : index % 4 == 1
               ? Colors.amber
               : index % 4 == 2
               ? Colors.pink
               : Colors.lime,)
```

This is the way if you really want to do it in single line if else ladder am also looking for a switch case in the same line